# In YAML, how to define a value for an item when it has sub-items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

How do I get YAML to allow me to give the value `The Cars` to `cars`:

```
en:
  cars: The Cars   #this causes a syntax error. If I remove 'The Cars', it works fine.
    fiat: Fiat
    bmw: Beemer
```

The reason I want a value for `cars` is that I want to be able to do this:

```
t('cars') # => The Cars
t('cars.fiat') # => Fiat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining a Hash, the value of `cars` is a hash whose keys are fiat and bmw

Comment: YAML is a way of serializing data, so you must choose the right data structures to hold the data you need. There is no "YAML magic"

Comment: I meant some YAML way to specify a default value, since a Hash can have a default value : `x = Hash.new('some default value')`.

Comment: A YAML "document" maps to a Ruby "hash." There is no notion of a "default value" in YAML, this is a Ruby-specific implementation.

Comment: @Zabba It's not about a default value. If you evaluate 'cars' you get {:fiat => "Fiat", :bmw => "Beemer"}. It's different from specifying a default value that would arise if you do 'cars[some_non_existing_key]'

Comment: Thanks. But could you help me out here: what is the "default value" (with the "=") on [this page](http://yaml.org/type/value.html) referring to? Appreciate your insight.

Comment: @Zabba yes that's the way to define a default value in YAML, but it doesn't fit your requirements. If you specify a default value for "cars" then that default value is going to show when you do "cars[non-existing_key]"

Comment: @Zabba copy the example in the page you pasted here and play with it. You can copy the text to a file and load it using YAML::load_file(file_path)